# Love2D Background Image taking color from other objects

Tags: lua, love2d

I had a question about how my love2d background image. It has been taking the color from different objects and tinting it. The background is supposed to be green and blue, but it is taking the color of the purple rectangle and tinting it purple. I am fairly new to lua and love2D, but I can't find any answers to this question.
[my game screen[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkr6A.png)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are drawing a background image, what you want to do is reset the drawing color to white before drawing the background.

```
love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255) --white
love.graphics.draw(background)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this solution worked out for you, please select it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First what you may want to do is set a neutral background before you set the image, using function

```
love.graphics.setBackgroundColor( red, green, blue )
```

This will initiate a set value of the background before adapting to the background picture.
I recommend [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gtp1-SHkNE4) to learn more, hope this helped :)